# Changing the date format in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I want to change my date format from "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM" to "dd/mm/yyyy".  I have script a script to do that but somehow it will not work.
See below is my cshtml code:

```
<div>
<div id="homeWelcome">
    Welcome @ViewBag.User
</div>
<div>
    Please see below the list of books you have rented.
</div>
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Date Rented</th>
                <th>Return Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)</th>
                    <th>dateFormat(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateRented))</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReturnDate)</th>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dateFormat(d){
    d.toISOString().substring(0, 10);

    }
</script>
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use toISOString in conjunction with a date object. Not a string like you are doing. toISOString is not used to convert dates.

Comment: It displays the date as : dateFormat(10/21/2015 12:00:00 AM). It will not call the function dateFormat.

Comment: *Date.prototype.toISOString* returns an ISO 8601 long format string like `2015-10-22T12:43:17Z`. You can do that, then rearrange the parts, but easier to just create a formatted string from the date using [*getDate*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.getdate), [*getMonth*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.getmonth) and [*getFullYear*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.getfullyear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `toISOString()` you need to transform your date string into a `Date` object and then proceed to format it:

```
function dateFormat(d){
    var date = new Date(d);
    return [date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDate(), date.getFullYear()].join('/');
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and then in the table I called the function dateFormat as: dateFormat(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateRented)).  But it displays the date as :  dateFormat(10/21/2015 12:00:00 AM).  It will not call the function dateFormat.

Comment: Yes, you are not invoking the function but just printing it out. Maybe consider doing the conversion server-side?

Comment: I prefer to do it on the client-side.  How can I invoke the function?

Comment: If you must, wrap `dateFormat(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateRented))` between `<script>` tags